# Modifying noise function to have sharp ridges

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

## Generating procedural 3D worlds

I am working on procedural world generation for a game in Unity3D. I have successfully managed to generate terrain with various levels of height via a couple of perlin noise functions.

I am sampling the functions based on the X,Y coordinates of of each point in a 16x16 chunk. Every chunk is rendered with no knowledge of its neighbor's.

Currently the world is smooth and varied and works well but I'm struggling to figure out how to implement the following:

### Cliff generation

I'm looking for a way to modify my noise function so that it produces some steep 'cutoffs' that would create cliffs and possibly overhang.

Are there any techniques that can make this easier?

### River generation

I'm also looking for the best way to create rivers. I believe I will have to do a second pass or create a separate noise function that can carve out the world on generation but again am struggling on how to implement this when chunks are independent of each other.

Any links to some algorithms or some general concepts on how this may be done would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Overhangs: Unity only bundles 2D noise, but you really need 3D noise for proper overhang generation. You can think of using 3D noise as recalculating the heightmap every time the vertical coordinate increases. Instead of `noises(x, y) + const > z ? solid : air`, it becomes `noises(x, y, z) + const > z ? solid : air`. Sometimes the noise value will increase just a little bit faster than z, and lead to an overhang. Compare against y if y is your vertical coordinate instead. You might want to add an additional frequency modifier for the vertical coordinate, so you can vary the level of overhangs to get the right result.

Which brings me to this: Unity's "PerlinNoise" function isn't very good, because it generates its namesake (old perlin noise) which can be [visibly grid-aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZgCk.jpg) (top is the perlin). Usually, I would use a simplex-type noise, for more interestingly distributed terrain features. I've put together [these public-domain noise generator classes](https://github.com/KdotJPG/OpenSimplex2/tree/master/csharp) which include a 3D function that doesn't have some of the same issues that other 3D "simplex" functions have. Use Noise3_XZBeforeY if Y is your vertical coordinate, or use Noise3_XYBeforeZ if Z is your vertical coordinate. Note that the output range is [-1,1] instead of [0,1]. To substitute directly for Unity's noise, you can do `Noise(...)*0.5+0.5`.

Generating 3D noise every point, especially multiple octaves of it, can be slow. Some games resort to using trilerp to reduce noise evaluations, but I [don't think that looks very good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omrBJ.jpg). Better to code smart and [only compute the noise octaves you need to](https://gist.github.com/KdotJPG/f8a072ed73aac51aef8f6d40d3ae825c/edit). Let `startingValue = const - z;`, or y if y is your vertical coordinate instead. If you're generating an isosurface (e.g. marching cubes), the terrain might look slightly different than computing every octave, but each point will be guaranteed to be the correct sign (i.e. solid or air). If you're generating blocks, the terrain will be exact.

Rivers can be as simple or as complex as you'd like. In a very simple case, you can modulate the terrain (or threshold / starting value if using the efficiency technique linked) when a 2D noise drops near zero. See the third column in noise comparison image. It creates paths, but you might notice that they can only split off in even numbers. You can mitigate this by generating three noise instances, and letting the boundaries be near when one's value trades off for another, as the maximum of the three. You can also use F2-F1 cellular noise, warped by simplex noise. I like to take 3D cellular noise and let the third coordinate be the output of a simplex noise. There are many more realistic ways to generate rivers, which I won't get into here. I haven't studied them all myself yet.